# CSS applied on submit button not working after submitting

Tags: javascript, css

I have a submit button on a form that submits the form on a php.page. I also added an onclick event on the submit button that changes it's opacity through javascript. The problem now is when I click the submit button, it changes it's opacity, the form is submitted, and after submission the button's opacity is back to 100% again. I want the opacity attribute remains on the button even after submitting the form. Check out my codes below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fadebtn(){
document.getElementById('submitbtn').style.opacity="0.4";
}
</script>

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn">
</form>
```

UPDATE: I fixed it now. Check the updated codes above and additional codes below.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn']))
{ 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
, 'fadebtn()'
, '</script>';
}
```

Comment: What is the submit action doing? Is it reloading the page (or) does it do some AJAX call? If it is reloading the same page then obviously the button will go back to its original state.

Comment: Seems like a postback i.e. reloading the same page.

Comment: the submit button will run php functions on the same page using isset($_POST['submitbtn'])

Comment: Assuming this isn't AJAX, I'd approach this by assigning the opacity to a CSS class. When the page is reloaded after posting back or the button is clicked, add that class to the submit button.

Comment: @clyde: Without more information on the reason for doing this opacity change it would be difficult to suggest. But you can try smclark89's comment above.

Comment: updated and fixed. PLs check above.

Comment: @clyde: Yes that is what I meant. Did that work or do you still have any issues?

Comment: @Harry yes it worked like how I wanted it to. Everytime the form is submitted, the javascript function fadebtn is called. Therefore after form submission and page reload the button's opacity is reduced to 40%.

Comment: @Harry I can't answer my own question for the meantime, I need 10+ reputation. If you want you can answer it by just copying the codes above and I'm gonna accept it as an answer. For everybody to know that this question has been resolved. ;)

Comment: It was actually @smclark89's suggestion, so let us wait for him (or her) to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

With button `type="submit"` and form `method="post"`this is going to post and cause a page reload. The style you apply with javscript will be reset once the page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is reloading the page.. 
I am not sure of your needs... but you will need to either need to set the css you want in the stylesheets or set the post action to "" and have jquery reset the opacity when the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple with CSS:

```
#submitbtn:active {
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

or

```
#submitbtn:focus {
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Which ever you like better.